# What happen to the Salt in Water Electrolysis

Tags: hydrogen

I haven't found yet what happen to the Salt Ions in Water during Electrolysis and is there an Electron Flow or Ion Flow. 
I have expierienced strong magnetic Forces between the Electrodes but couldnt measure an outside Magnetic Field.

Answer (score 0):

When a battery is connected to an electrolytic cell one electrode becomes positively charged the other negatively charged. The ions in the liquid are attracted to the electrode with the opposite charge and move through solution. Ions with a negative charge move to the positive anode (anions), Ions with a positive charge migrate to the negative cathode (cations).

Ionic solids produce electrolytes. When an ionic solid is dissolved in water the aqueous ions are free to move and they carry the current. The anions of the salt and water give up electrons which flow through the circuit. The anions are oxidized at the anode while the cations of the salt and water recieve the electrons and are reduced at the cathode.

Cations will cluster around the cathode and anions will cluster at the anode. It is usually easier to displace hydrogen atoms from water molecules in the aqua ion than to displace the cation from the system  so electrons from the cathode react with water molecules , and hydrogen is displaced.

The result is decomposition of water molecules:

2H-OH(l) + 2e- → H2(g) + 2OH-(aq)

The solution becomes alkaline around the cathode due to the hydroxide ions being formed. If a metal is above hydrogen in the electrochemical series, hydrogen will always be produced at the cathode during electrolysis of solutions of its salts. If the ionic salt consists of a metal below hydrogen in the electrochemical series, electrolysis of its salt solution will always produce metal at the cathode.

Both ion flow and electron flow are occurring.

The intensity of an electromagnetic field reduces significantly the further away from the source.

Answer (score -1):

You're mixing two different concepts.

First a magnetic field has nothing to do with an electrochemical cell. A magnetic field is created when a direct current flows in coil. Think of wrapping a wire around a nail.

As far as the ions in solution, the cations have a mass flow in one direction and the anions have a mass flow in the other. Think of having a theoretical "force field" that can gate anions and cations. As many cations would flow through as anions while current flows in the system.

Comment: An electromagnetic coil creates an electromagnetic field when a current is applied, energy radiates away from the source,  a regular magnet is static  and creates a Near magnetic or magnetic field where energy is stored...

Comment: Sorry I meant a electrochemical cell creates an electromagnetic field which is an electric field and a magnetic field at the same time.

Comment: @Joel - Well you're right any current flowing will create a magnetic field, but in a typical straight wire the field is very weak. An electromagnetic coil creates a much stronger field which is very easily detected. // A wire concentrates the current flow in a very small cross-section.  To detect the magnetic field in the electrochemical cell itself would probably require some sort of very special cell design and some sort of very special detector (e.g. a SQUID).